# How to use AES 256 in CTR mode?

Tags: php, encryption, aes, haxe

As I am trying to encrypt in haxe & decrypt in php using AES 256, CTR, I've noticed that if data to be encrypted longer than 15 character, the result of decryption would be blank, any idea about this restriction?

I encrypt in haxe like:

```
var input:String = "abcdefghijklmno"; // limited to 15 char to be decrypted, other wise, I get blank result..
var utf8Bytes:Array<Int> = UTF8.textToBytes(input);

var aes256iv:Array<Int> = UTF8.textToBytes("1234567890123456");
        var aes256key:Array<Int> = UTF8.textToBytes("12345678901234561234567890123456");
        var aes256enc:Array<Int> = AES.encrypt(aes256key, PKCS7.pad(utf8Bytes, 16), OperationMode.CTR, aes256iv); // Encrypt in CTR mode. Needs padding.
        var aes256dec:Array<Int> = PKCS7.unpad(AES.decrypt(aes256key, aes256enc, OperationMode.CTR, aes256iv)); // Decrypt in CTR mode. Needs unpadding.

writeLine("AES-256 (CTR mode) encrypted in UTF-8: " + Base64.encode(aes256enc));
        writeLine("AES-256 (CTR mode) decrypted in UTF-8: " + UTF8.bytesToText(aes256dec));
```

In PHP, I decrypt:

```
$aes256i = "1234567890123456";
        $aes256k = "12345678901234561234567890123456";

        //print $input;

        $aes256e = Base64::decode($input);
        //print "Base64: " . $aes256e . "<br/><br/>\n";
        $aes256d = PKCS7::unpad(AES::decrypt($aes256k, $aes256e, "ctr", $aes256i)); // Needs unpadding.
        //
        print "AES-256 (CTR mode) decrypted in UTF-8: " . $aes256d . "<br/><br/>\n";


public static function decrypt($key, $text, $mode = "ecb", $iv = null)
    {
        $size = MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128; // AES fixed to 128 bits
        if (isset($iv)) return mcrypt_decrypt($size, $key, $text, $mode, $iv);
        return @mcrypt_decrypt($size, $key, $text, $mode);
    }
```

So, any one can help? p.s: if I decrypt in haxe lib, there is no limits of data encrypted, what would I miss at PHP side? I am using the same keys both sides..

Comment: Try encrypting and decrypting in the same programming language  and on the same system first.  When that works, search through stack overclow for discussions about encrypting and decrypting across different character sets.

Comment: It works normally, even with data longer than 15 character..

Comment: Define 'normally'. Did you test on both sides?

Comment: yes, on PHP, on haxe, I did encrypt, decrypt for long text, it worked normally, however, the problem happens when encrypt in haxe, decrypt in PHP

Comment: Remove the padding first, it is not required for CTR mode. Besides, CTR seems unknown, try "stream" instead.

Comment: `$mode = "ecb"` Why are you defaulting to ECB mode if you're trying to handle CTR mode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> public static function decrypt($key, $text, $mode = "ecb", $iv = null)
> ```

Changing `$mode = "ecb"` to `$mode = "ctr"` would solve your immediate problem.

However, there are deeper problems here:

1. You're [using mcrypt](https://paragonie.com/blog/2015/05/if-you-re-typing-word-mcrypt-into-your-code-you-re-doing-it-wrong).
2. You're using [unauthenticated encryption](https://tonyarcieri.com/all-the-crypto-code-youve-ever-written-is-probably-broken).

If you're trying to encrypt data, you'll be better served using [libsodium](https://libsodium.gitbook.io/doc/bindings_for_other_languages) instead.

- For PHP, you can use PHP 7.2+, PHP < 7.2 with ext/sodium from PECL, or [sodium_compat](https://github.com/paragonie/sodium_compat).
- For HaXe, you can either use [the HaXe bindings](https://github.com/RudolfVonKrugstein/haxe_libsodium) or [sodium-plus](https://github.com/paragonie/sodium-plus) to encrypt data.

Regardless of which configuration you go with, you'll want to refer to the [libsodium quick reference](https://paragonie.com/blog/2017/06/libsodium-quick-reference-quick-comparison-similar-functions-and-which-one-use) to figure out which function to use (and how).

Comment: The question is 6 years old! I appreciate your answer :)